# Carriage Return Oracle 10g SQL

Tags: sql, excel, oracle10g, carriage-return

I'm trying to write a report that I will send out in Excel which concatenates two records into the same cell, displaying a carriage return between each record. I have been trying with ||chr(10) || chr(13) || but this only works if I run as a script and not when I run the query in Excel.

Is there a better way of forcing a carriage return?

The select statement looks like this:

```
select distinct
cap.cap_stuc "Application ID"
,stu.stu_surn "Surname"
,initcap(stu.stu_fnm1) "First Name"
,min(decode(rn, 1, choices.cap_pref)) || ' ' || min(decode(rn, 1,choices.cap_mcrc)) || ' ' || min(decode(rn, 1, choices.crs_name)) || chr(10)||chr(13) || min(decode(rn, 2, choices.cap_pref)) || ' ' ||  min(decode(rn, 2, choices.cap_mcrc)) || ' ' ||  min(decode(rn, 2, choices.crs_name)) "App Details"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Windows system, I believe you have it backwards and it needs to be ... || chr(13) || chr(10) || ...

It should be CR + LF, which is ASCII characters 13 + 10, not LF + CR.

You could also try writing a Java stored procedure to return your data, and then putting in a newline is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a solution.

Firstly, you were correct, it was backwards, so I concatenated with || chr(13) || chr(10) ||

This meant the carriage returns were there but not showing in Excel. The solution? Wrapping the text in the relevant cells

So infuriating that the answer was so simple!